# Fast, line-wise full text search for Unix directory structure

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to create a GUI for searching through a large number of huge configuration files (approx 60000 files, each one with a size between 20 KByte to 50 MByte). Those files are also updated frequently (~3 times/day).

So far I have found [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), but found no way to have them return the list of matching lines including a line number for each matching document.

What we currently do is we convert each text file to XML:

```
<xml>
   <line number="1">foobar</line>
   <line number="2">barfoo</line>
   ...
</xml>
```

and store the result in an eXist-db. However, storing documents is way too slow, so we need an alternative.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Opinion: If you have large amounts of volatile text data you need fast access to, converting them to XML will make your problems much harder to solve.

> **Any better ideas?**

Leave the files as text and use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/demo.html)?

(I'm assuming that `grep` doesn't cut it)

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use XML”   Now they have two problems."

Comment: The only way to make Lucene return line numbers is by storing each line in a separate document. This, however, makes updating a document hard (and it is probably impossible to make updates fast).

Comment: @knipknap: I can't work out if that's how [this example](http://www.tom-carden.co.uk/2007/08/01/a-quick-less-certain-note-on-using-lucene-in-processing/) does it. ([Applet with source](http://www.tom-carden.co.uk/p5/simple_lucene_demo/applet/))

Comment: The demo only adds one file, but yes, it stores each line as a separate document using the loop at the comment "pull the data from our list and add it to the index" in SimpleLucene.java. Since they don't do updates, this is not a problem.